# How to separate words with "space" from: (example1,example2,...) to (example1, example2, ...)

Tags: php, title, space

I have a problem in php code with title output.

***Example:***
If I have words in title like this: *"example1,example2,example3,example4,..."* this title expands my cloud div style.

The output ***.$row['title'].*** shoud *separate* words from example1,example2,example3 to example1, example2, example3, ... with spaces but it doesn't. How to change this code that this will hapened?

Thank's.

```
<?php


function print_cloud()
{ global $use_ads_scrl; $res=""; if ($use_ads_scrl=="yes"){$res=print_cloud2();}  return $res; }

function print_cloud2()
{

global $table_ads, $HTTP_GET_VARS;

$city_sch="";
if ($HTTP_GET_VARS['city']!=""){$city_sch="and city='".$HTTP_GET_VARS['city']."' ";}

$sql_query="select * from $table_ads where (adcommkey is null or adcommkey=0) and visible=1 $city_sch
order by RAND() limit 10";

$sql_res=mysql_query("$sql_query");

$min = '10'; // Minimum font size in pixel.
$max = '22'; // Maximum font size in pixel.

$k1=""; $html_res="";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)){
$k1="1";
if($row['adphotos']=='yes'){$check_ph=$photo_mark;} else {$check_ph="";}

$html_res=$html_res."
<a style='font-size:".rand($min,$max)."px; font-family:tahoma,sans-serif;'    
    class=\"tag_cloud\" 
        href='index.php?md=details&id= ".$row['idnum']." '> ".$row['title']." </a> 
";


}

$html_res="
$html_res
";

if ($k1==""){$html_res="";}

return $html_res;
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code?

Answer (score 3):

You could use str_replace for this:

```
echo str_replace(",", ", ", $the_string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just split the string by a comma and put it together again using a comma and a space as glue:

```
 $row['title'] = implode( ', ', explode( ',', .$row['title'] ) );
```

Comment: This is much slower compared to str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $txt = $row['title'];   
    $txt = explode(",", $txt);
    foreach($txt as $key => $value) {
       echo $value.", ";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer seems too simple to be correct but here it goes.

Change this code:

```
$html_res=$html_res."
<a style='font-size:".rand($min,$max)."px; font-family:tahoma,sans-serif;'    
    class=\"tag_cloud\" 
        href='index.php?md=details&id= ".$row['idnum']." '> ".$row['title']." </a> 
";
```

to this code:

```
$html_res=$html_res."
<a style='font-size:".rand($min,$max)."px; font-family:tahoma,sans-serif;'    
    class=\"tag_cloud\" 
        href='index.php?md=details&id= ".$row['idnum']." '> ".$row['title'].",</a> ";
```

Updated full code is below:

```
<?php


function print_cloud()
{ global $use_ads_scrl; $res=""; if ($use_ads_scrl=="yes"){$res=print_cloud2();}  return $res; }

function print_cloud2()
{

global $table_ads, $HTTP_GET_VARS;

$city_sch="";
if ($HTTP_GET_VARS['city']!=""){$city_sch="and city='".$HTTP_GET_VARS['city']."' ";}

$sql_query="select * from $table_ads where (adcommkey is null or adcommkey=0) and visible=1 $city_sch
order by RAND() limit 10";

$sql_res=mysql_query("$sql_query");

$min = '10'; // Minimum font size in pixel.
$max = '22'; // Maximum font size in pixel.

$k1=""; $html_res="";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)){
$k1="1";
if($row['adphotos']=='yes'){$check_ph=$photo_mark;} else {$check_ph="";}

$html_res=$html_res."
<a style='font-size:".rand($min,$max)."px; font-family:tahoma,sans-serif;'    
    class=\"tag_cloud\" 
        href='index.php?md=details&id= ".$row['idnum']." '> ".$row['title'].",</a> ";


}

$html_res="
$html_res
";

if ($k1==""){$html_res="";}

return $html_res;
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, you just ad the (,) to the end of (.$row['title'].",) but the problem is that the output $row['title' already is complete sentence. For example test1,test2,test3,... Thanks for help

Comment: I see. Then feeela's solution seems appropriate.